# WPF XAML - Adding multiple styles to resource dictionary which target rowdefinition

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary

Thanks for your thoughts in helping a relative beginner understand WPF.

I am trying to use the following style template in an XAML file for a WPF application:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}"
                        x:Key="hideIfNotDischarged">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DischargedBy28Days,
                                Mode=OneWay}" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type RowDefinition}"
                        x:Key="hideIfOutcomeKnownAndAlive">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsKnownDead,
                                Mode=OneWay}" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Height" Value="0" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

Which will be later used in a grid like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="30" />
        <RowDefinition Style="{StaticResource hideIfNotDischarged}" />
        ...
```

However, if there is more than 1 style element targeting Type `RowDefinition` AND ALSO the `ResourceDictionary` is nested within a `MergedDictionary` (even with only a single child `ResourceDictionary` to merge) the application fails with
`System.Windows.ResourceDictionary.DeferrableContent`: Item has already been added.

That is, despite the fact the 2 styles have different keys, the resource dictionary is trying to add a dictionary item with name based purely on the target type (and ignoring the key).

Any help with how I might overcome this would be most appreciated.

Comment: You can have multiple `RowDefinition` styles in your application as long as they have a unique key, I just copied the 2 style you have above into a ResourceDictionary and it compiled fine and both styles can be applied, I think you have another set of these styles somewhere or VS is having a caching issue, try clean and rebuilding the solution

Comment: Thank you for testing - I had tried to simplify the code but have found after further testing it is to do with using merged dictionaries. The codehas been edited

Comment: try declaring the `x:key` before the `TargetType` to avoid the `ResourceDictionary` checking the `TargetType` exists before it realizes it has a `x:Key`

Comment: You are a genius - thank you - moving the x:key before target type worked!! - please add an answer so I can mark you as answered

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Xaml` is parsed left to right so I think its checking the `ResourceDictionary` or the other `MergedDictionaries` if the `TargetType` (default identifier if no x:Key is used) exists before it realizes it has an `x:Key` identifier

Try setting the `x:Key` before the `TargetType`.

this could be a bug in the Xaml parser or it could be by design, It may be worth a look on Microsoft Connect

Comment: Unbelievable! I lost two hours trying to find out what was wrong with my XAML and eventually discovered your answer. Thank you!

Comment: I was using `x:Name` instead of `x:Key` and that was my issue =/

Comment: Holy $%@!, I can't believe this is actually the issue.  I lost a few hours tonight, when I can't really afford it, too!  Effed up part is the designer works just fine, its at *runtime* it died for me.  Also, the order didn't matter when the styles were inside the `<UserControl.Resources>` directly, but when put in a nested dictionary in the control it started failing.    In my case it was just `TargetType="Label"` though.